# convert pandas timedelta output from days to quarter

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, datetimeindex

here is my input:

```
 import pandas as pd
 dt_one = pd.to_datetime('2015/5/25') - pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()
 dt_two = pd.to_datetime('2016/9/15') - pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()
```

here is my output:

```
(dt_two - dt_one)
Out[75]: Timedelta('457 days 00:00:00')
```

however, i desire to convert the above time delta from days in between two dates to quarters in between those two dates. How can I achieve this? The output should be '5'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the number of quarters like this:

```
In [106]: dt_one = pd.to_datetime('2015/5/25') - pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()
     ...: dt_two = pd.to_datetime('2016/9/15') - pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()
     ...: 

In [107]: ((dt_two.year - dt_one.year)*12 + (dt_two.month - dt_one.month))/3.0
Out[107]: 5.0
```